# Update bearing in Google MapView

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having trouble updating the bearing of my map using a MapView from Google Maps. Under normal conditions everything works, but I'd like to offset the center of the map so my user can see ahead of them further. to do this I add a top padding of 60%. This also works. When I go to rotate the map using the following code, the map pivots off the center of the view ignoring the padding.

```
CameraPosition cameraPos = googleMap.getCameraPosition();
cameraPos = new CameraPosition.Builder(cameraPos)
        .bearing(newBearing)
        .build();
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPos));
```

On the other hand, if I use the last known location from the GPS the rotation is done about the actual camera target (respecting the padding)

```
cameraPos = new CameraPosition.Builder(cameraPos)
        .target(lastKnownLocation)
        .bearing(newBearing)
        .build();
```

Note, that using the last location from the camera directly does nothing.

Comment: Hello, I'm experiencing this problem too. Have you ever managed to find a solution?